# Is there a way to modify windows 7 to create a new file from image/text paste?

Tags: windows-7

Like when I take a screenshot, I want to be able to go to a folder with explorer and hit ctrl+v and have a png or something show up with the image in it, or when I have a log I'm copying I want to paste into a folder and have a text document appear with it in it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, this is possible.

Long answer: There are a lot of third party copy paste tools out there, and even 1st party tools (press windows key, type "snipping tool", press return). They all make taking screenshots, editing them, and saving them as files a lot easier. I don't know one that works exactly the way you describe, but it's very likely that one exists. If none of the tools out there works exactly the way you want, you can always write your own.

Several existing tools allow you to automatically save screenshots in a specific folder ( this is even built in in Windows 8), which isn't exactly what you are asking for but close.

Comment: I'll see if I can find some way of creating a script for this with a ctrl+v as shortcut, but I'll just keep the question open for now in case someone else has a tool already pre-created and if not I'll mark this as the answer

Comment: Give it a couple weeks, someone might know the correct answer. When writing a script I'd actually recommend to hook into PrintScreen, create a temp file, then put it in the copy paste buffer.

Comment: so...wait...what?

Comment: how am I supposed to start a chat here?

Comment: and I meant could you please rephrase the other comment in a for dummies format

Answer (score 1):

While this seems like a good idea, I don't think there are any third party tools available currently that have this exact behavior in Windows (or any other OS for that matter).

But as [Peter said](https://superuser.com/a/824998/114046), there are tools like [PicPick](http://www.picpick.org/en/features) which auto-save screenshots in a folder which you can specify. There are also clipboard managers like [Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/) which save your `Ctrl + C` copies into its database which you can access from the program itself.